# Multiple GetHTML Attributes in Apache Nifi

Tags: attributes, apache-nifi

Is there any way to perform multiple `GetHTMLElement` in the same dataflow? I am trying to scrapy some attributes first performing the `GetHTMLElement` (selecting attribute) and after performing an `UpdateAttribute` processor

```
(attrib: ${HTMLElement})
```

This first part works well, but when I try to perform a second `GetHTMLElement`, it can't parse anything from the flowContent...

I performed them in 2 separated ways and merged them with `MergeContent` and work... But now I need to perform 2 *"Gets"* in different parts of a flow (after a split) and the merge won't work...

Thank you for your help... I've tryed to ask it in Hortonworks community (https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/131614/multiple-gethtmlelement.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that `GetHTMLElement` can either put the extracted element into a flowfile *attribute* or the flowfile *content* depending on the configured `Destination` property value. `GetHTMLElement` has four *relationships* that it can output:

- **element not found** - Element could not be found in the HTML document. The original HTML input will remain in the FlowFile content unchanged. Relationship 'original' will not be invoked in this scenario.
- **success** - Successfully parsed HTML element
- **original** - The original HTML input
- **invalid html** - The input HTML syntax is invalid

In the **success** relationship, the resulting flowfile will either have the content of the extracted element, or if the element was put in an attribute, **no content**. This is because of the way elements are matched (see [GetHTMLElement#186](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-html-bundle/nifi-html-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/GetHTMLElement.java#L186)). You can route the **original** relationship to the second `GetHTMLElement` processor to extract the element, but as you described, you'll have two unique flowfiles, each with one element.

I filed a Jira [NIFI-4356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4356) to improve the handling of this case by keeping the original content in the resulting flowfiles when the destination is *attribute*.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Would be nice to implement CSS Selector for each property you can add, getting many attributes from the HTML with only one processor (like EvaluateJSONPath or EvaluateXPath)